# fsck hangs on boot checking /boot/efi partition

Tags: boot, fsck

After upgrading from  20.04 to 22.04 on my home server yesterday, it now takes over 5 hours to boot up! It eventually does come up and seems to be fully operational, though.

The top entry in `systemd-analyze blame` is:

```
5h 30min 43.446s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-00282959\x2d708e\x2d4f54\x2d8a72\x2d8a0ed3b6f7cd.service
```

That partition that it's trying to check is the `/boot/efi` partition:

```
$ ll /dev/disk/by-partuuid/00282959-708e-4f54-8a72-8a0ed3b6f7cd 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 23 01:02 /dev/disk/by-partuuid/00282959-708e-4f54-8a72-8a0ed3b6f7cd -> ../../sdt1
$ mount | grep sdt1
/dev/sdt1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
$ cat /etc/fstab | grep efi
PARTUUID=00282959-708e-4f54-8a72-8a0ed3b6f7cd  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
$ lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid /dev/sdt1
NAME MOUNTPOINT LABEL  SIZE FSTYPE UUID                                 PARTUUID
sdt1 /boot/efi         200M vfat   48F8-7B80                            00282959-708e-4f54-8a72-8a0ed3b6f7cd
```

Any ideas as to why this tiny, 200M partition is delaying boot by over 5 hours? Or am I misinterpreting the information?

Any recommendations for what I can do to fix the problem?

Comment: What does dosfsck show? `man dosfsck` sudo fsck.vfat -t -a /dev/sdXY # where X is drive and Y is partition. sdt1? How many drives & partitions? Lots of drives and various formats can add to boot time, but should not be hours unless mounting partitions that do not exist and it has to time out. Or are these network drives & the network is not available?

Comment: Thanks. Not a network drive. It's a SATA SSD. Manually running `fsck` is also taking hours, and it does spit out some strange errors: `FATs differ - using first FAT.` and multiple iterations of `Cluster 92320 out of range (249816035 > 189519). Setting to EOF.` I'm running with `-a` now, so maybe it'll repair it? If not, should I try `chkdsk` on a Windows box? Maybe just reformat and `rsync` the files? I have 4 copies of this partition on 4 different drives in the box, so I can play around with it a bit.

Comment: Will it format? It is strange error. Does drive have smart data to see if drive issue? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools If Ubuntu and you have Disks (gnome-disks), in upper right corner icon is smart data, also. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2445397&page=2&p=13965854#post13965854

Comment: Thanks for you help, @oldfred. I was able to reformat the partition and rsync all the files over from another copy. The `fsck` command completes successfully pretty much instantly afterwards, and I can boot up the system in well under a minute. Must have been a seriously corrupted volume.